# JavaScript: Why getting last inserted values?

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

I am getting familiar with the prototype world of JavaScript and `this` keyword. I am new to Web-world. Today when I started playing with prototype I saw some strange behavior but I am not able to get why this is happening. I've created a constructor `Group` as following:

```
// Code goes here
function Group(config) {
  this.config = config;
  this.getId = function() {
    return this.config.id;
  };
  this.setId = function(id) {
    this.config.id = id;
  };
}
```

I use it in one `MyGroup` constructor like this:

```
function MyGroup(config) {
  var myAttrs = ['id', 'name'];
  this.g = new Group(config);
  addGetterSetter(MyGroup, this.g, myAttrs)
}
```

`addGetterSetter` is the function I wrote to add getter and setter dynamically to the attributes of `MyGroup`.

```
var GET = 'get',
  SET = 'set';

function capitalize(str) {
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}

function addGetterSetter(constructor, target, attrs) {

  function addGetter(constructor, target, attr) {
    var method = GET + capitalize(attr);
    constructor.prototype[method] = function() {
      return target[method]();
    };
  }

  function addSetter(constructor, target, attr) {
    var method = SET + capitalize(attr);
    constructor.prototype[method] = function(value) {
      return target[method](value);
    };
  }
  for (var index = 0; index < attrs.length; index++) {
    addGetter(constructor, target, attrs[index]);
    addSetter(constructor, target, attrs[index]);
  }
}
```

Now when I use `MyGroup`,`Group` like this:

```
var items = [{
  id: 123,
  name: 'Abc'
}, {
  id: 131,
  name: 'Bca'
}, {
  id: 22,
  name: 'bc'
}];
var groups = [];
items.forEach(function(item) {
  var g = new MyGroup(item);
  groups.push(g);
});

groups.forEach(function(g) {
  console.log(g.getId()); //don't know why this logs 22 three times instead of all ids
});
```

In `group.forEach` I don't know why the id of the last item is getting logged. I am not able to understand what is going wrong. And how will I be able to get of the group for which `g.getId()` is invoked. Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EJqFGiD8Yt5EeNhpzOwz?p=preview)

Comment: In line 14 of script.js I get following error: `TypeError: target[method] is not a function`. It seems that the method `getName` cannot be created as you expect.

Comment: It's working for me. Don't know why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're adding methods to prototype and you overwrite in the loop each time the previous function so the function hold reference to last object when forEach loop finishes. What you need is to add function to this object:

```
function MyGroup(config) {
  var myAttrs = ['id', 'name'];
  this.g = new Group(config);
  addGetterSetter(this, this.g, myAttrs)
}
function addGetterSetter(object, target, attrs) {

  function addGetter(object, target, attr) {
    var method = GET + capitalize(attr);
    object[method] = function() {
      return target[method]();
    };
  }

  function addSetter(object, target, attr) {
    var method = SET + capitalize(attr);
    object[method] = function(value) {
      return target[method](value);
    };
  }
  for (var index = 0; index < attrs.length; index++) {
    addGetter(object, target, attrs[index]);
    addSetter(object, target, attrs[index]);
  }
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x0k69xwe/)**

Comment: Got it brother. Thank you very much. Can you please share a good link where I can found detailed explanation of JS prototypes? I need to understand it fully.

Comment: Try [google](https://www.google.pl/search?sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&btnG=Search&q=understanding+javascript+prototype&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1)